# Creating an R function to use mclapply from the multicore package

Tags: r, multicore, montecarlo, lapply, mclapply

I need to analyze some simulated data with the following structure:

```
h   c   x1              y1              x1c10
1   0   37.607056431    104.83097593    5
1   1   27.615251557    140.85532974    10
1   0   34.68915314     114.59312842    2
1   1   30.090387454    131.60485642    9
1   1   39.274429397    106.76042522    10
1   0   33.839385007    122.73681319    2
...
```

where h ranges from 1 to 2500, and indexes the Monte Carlo sample, each sample with 1000 observations. I'm analysing these data with the following code that gives me two objects (fnN1, fdQB101):

```
mc<-2500 ##create loop index
fdN1<-matrix(0,mc,1000)
fnQB101 <- matrix(0,mc,1000) ##create 2500x1000 storage matrices, elements zero

for(j in 1:mc){

fdN1[j,] <- dnorm(residuals(lm(x1 ~ c,data=s[s$h==j,])), 
                     mean(residuals(lm(x1 ~ c,data=s[s$h==j,]))), 
                          sd(residuals(lm(x1 ~ c,data=s[s$h==j,]))))

x1c10<-as.matrix(subset(s,s$h==j,select=x1c10))

fdQB100 <- as.matrix(predict(polr(as.factor(x1c10) ~ c , 
                                    method="logistic", data=s[s$h==j,]),
                                         type="probs"))

indx10<- as.matrix(cbind(as.vector(seq(1:nrow(fdQB100))),x1c10))

fdQB101[j,] <- fdQB100[indx10]

}
```

The objects fdN1 and fdQB101 are 2500x1000 matrices with predicted probabilities as elements. I need to create a function out of this loop that I can call with lapply() or mclapply(). When I wrap this in the following function command:

```
ndMC <- function(mc){

for(j in 1:mc){
...
}
return(list(fdN1,fdQB101))

}
lapply(mc,ndMC)
```

the objects fdN1 and fdQB101 are each returned as 2500x1000 matrices of zeros, instead of the predicted probabilities. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you perhaps post some example data? I suggest using `dput` to output several rows.

Comment: @Jason: example data has been added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the `data.table` package.  Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(h=rep(1L,6), c=c(0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,0L),
           X1=c(37.607056431,27.615251557,34.68915314,30.090387454,39.274429397,33.839385007),
           y1=c(104.83097593,140.85532974,114.59312842,131.60485642,106.76042522,122.73681319),
           x1c10=c(5L,10L,2L,9L,10L,2L))

## Create a linear model for every grouping of variable h:
fdN1.partial<-dt[,list(lm=list(lm(X1~c))),by="h"]

## Retrieve the linear model for h==1:
fdN1.partial[h==1,lm]
## [[1]]
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = X1 ~ c)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            c  
##      35.379       -3.052
```

You could also write a function to generalize this solution:

```
f.dnorm<-function(y,x) {
  f<-lm(y ~ x)
  out<-list(dnorm(residuals(f), mean(residuals(f)), sd(residuals(f))))
  return(out)
}

## Generate two dnorm lists for every grouping of variable h:
dt.lm<-dt[,list(dnormX11=list(f.dnorm(X1,rep(1,length(X1)))), dnormX1c=list(f.dnorm(X1,c))),by="h"]

## Retrieve one of the dnorm lists for h==1:
unlist(dt.lm[h==1,dnormX11])
##          1          2          3          4          5          6 
## 0.06296194 0.03327407 0.08884549 0.06286739 0.04248756 0.09045784
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Is there a way to put this into an lapply() or mclapply() command? I'm trying to do some parallel processing using the latter.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with those, and I'm not sure I completely understand the structure of your actual data or what you might be doing with it afterward...  You've got 2500*1000 = 2.5M rows, right?  I created a table with 2.5M rows based on your example, and the `dt.lm` table took 13sec to generate.  In other words, do you need to parallelize?

Comment: Yes, your proposed method is fast. But I'm looking for a way to use mclapply() from the multicore package. Thanks.